# Can I lock autoexposure (AE Lock) while also using back button Lock AF on my Canon 1300D?

Tags: canon, exposure, autofocus, auto-exposure-lock

I have a Canon 1300D. I'm using back button by custom function to auto focus. I was just wondering if there's any way to also set any other button to lock AE while using back button to lock focus.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. If you set the custom function to `1`, then the **shutter button** is the `AE lock` button on half press, while the back button does AF.

Only in modes 2 and 3 there's no `AE lock` available.

Comment: Is that true with all metering modes? On many Canon cameras the half press locks exposure in Evaluative metering mode, but does not lock it in Spot/Partial/Center Weighted Average.

Comment: It's what the manual says, and the custom function menu. Just tried it on my 600d, too.

Comment: Look at page 115 of the same manual, which says what I commented above.

Comment: I can only assume they mean the default setting here, not when the button is explicitly set to AE lock (and the star is displayed).

Comment: What metering mode are you using?

Comment: i've tried all of them, obviously.

Comment: Nothing online is obvious unless explicitly stated.